# Maxent SDM projections coming up almost entirely blue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, maxent, habitat-modeling, wildlife-ecology

I have been generating SDM models and projections in Maxent. I have had some success with one set of variables (some Hydroshed variables mixed with World CLIM variables); however, I am having a bit of trouble with a model based solely on World CLIM variables.

I used a Pearson correlation matrix to select eight World CLIM variables, which model well with my species' occurrence data. The issue arises, when I ask Maxent to project on future World CLIM variables - the returned projection is almost entirely blue. There are a few specs of red and yellow (indicating prediction probabilities), but the vast majority of the projection is blue (indicating zero prediction probability). I tried rerunning the model with clamping turned off, but the problem persisted.

I am relatively novice with Maxent, so I was wondering if I am overlooking a setting that may help correct this issue. I am a bit confused, because when I ran the projection with the Hydroshed variables and some of the same World CLIM variables, the future projection looked just fine.

I am using ArcGIS Pro from Esri and the Maxent application (version 3.4.4) to make my models. I am taking rasters (ASCII files) of each variable, clipping them to my study extent, then feeding them through maxent with my occurrence data to generate the models.

I am attaching pictures of my current Maxent settings:

[image: Pic1] [image: Pic2]

I am also attaching a picture of my functioning model (top map in the picture) and the problematic blue projection of future variables (bottom map in the picture):

[image: Pic3]

As you can see in the future projection, there is some light wisps of color in the far North-East, so it appears the projection is at least being made without any major errors.

As a side note, I've played around with selectively using only certain regions of the occurrence data for modeling and noticed that certain selections will generate more normal looking future projections, while others will produce mostly blue maps, like the one in Picture 3.

Why are some of my future projections for only CLIM variables coming back almost completely blue, while projections made with CLIM and Hydroshed variables are coming back normal looking?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in your Question.

Comment: @Vince apologies, I just edited this question into the original text:  Why are some of my future projections for only CLIM variables coming back almost completely blue, while projections made with CLIM and Hydroshed variables are coming back normal looking?